# Rename xcdatamodel file

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode4

What do in need to do to rename the .xcdatamodel file. Renaming .xcdatamodel filename, along with changing ...

```
NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"newfilename" withExtension:@"momd"];
__managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
return __managedObjectModel;
```

and

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"newfilename.sqlite"];
```

doesn't work! I get following error:

```
2011-04-11 17:19:54.164 ProjectName[5826:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Cannot create an NSPersistentStoreCoordinator with a nil model'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00fa15a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x010f5313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreData                            0x00013853 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator initWithManagedObjectModel:] + 419
    3   ProjectName                         0x00003471 -[ProjectNameAppDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator] + 257
    4   ProjectName                         0x000031a4 -[ProjectNameAppDelegate managedObjectContext] + 100
    5   ProjectName                         0x000028ca -[ProjectNameAppDelegate makeSplitViewController] + 762
    6   ProjectName                         0x00002d44 -[ProjectNameAppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] + 68
    7   UIKit                               0x001f3c89 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesForURL:payload:suspended:] + 1163
    8   UIKit                               0x001f5d88 -[UIApplication _runWithURL:payload:launchOrientation:statusBarStyle:statusBarHidden:] + 439
    9   UIKit                               0x00200617 -[UIApplication handleEvent:withNewEvent:] + 1533
    10  UIKit                               0x001f8abf -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 71
    11  UIKit                               0x001fdf2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x018f9992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00f82944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00ee2cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x00edff83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x00edf840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x00edf761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    18  UIKit                               0x001f57d2 -[UIApplication _run] + 623
    19  UIKit                               0x00201c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    20  ProjectName                         0x00002599 main + 121
    21  ProjectName                         0x00002515 start + 53
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
```

Note: I'm using Xcode4.

Comment: I guess more details would bring answers, like an exception message/trace.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have been having the same problem with Xcode 4. Don't know what the behaviour is in Xcode 3.

Firstly, when you add a core data model in xcode, you actually get a .xcdatamodeld file which is a package like the .xcodeproj file. In finder, you can right click it and "Show Package Contents".
You'll see it contains a .xcdatamodel file.

It seems to me you can't rename it fully using xcode. Xcode will change the name of the package file (the momd) as you see it in the UI, but on the file system it has not actually changed.

The nil model error you get is because it can't find the newfilename momd since it still has the old name on disk. (I guess)

I worked around this by creating a new model with the name I wanted, then in the existing model, you can click-drag and select your entities, then just paste them into the new model file. You can then delete the old one and commit all the changes to your SCM.

Comment: This fixed it for me - recreating and deleting.

Comment: Interesting issue with Xcode 12...due to UI changes, I didn't click and drag my entities, I copied and pasted them into the new model file. In the new file, many of my inverse relationships, delete rules and all of my codegen settings were lost. Once I fixed those problems, everything was fine.

Answer (score 32):

There is a hidden file called .xccurrentversion which should be in the same location as your whatever.xcdatamodeld file. Inside there is a reference to your model which needs to be updated with the new name.

In some cases, you'll have to remove the .xcdatamodeld file from the project and add it again to make it work.

Comment: +1 for full understanding of problem. Renamed an .xcdatamodeld file and this problem appeared. Why can't Xcode automatically change this??

Comment: worked form me.. the file mentioned is a hidden file. Here are the steps to show hidden files in MAC OS X Lion http://www.joshklein.net/how-to-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-lion

Comment: Brilliant !   My app was continually crashing since trying to (carefully) rename the project...  removing & re-adding the .xcdatamodelId file fixed the issue.  Thanks!

Comment: Wow, that is pretty appalling. Really does seem the only way to make Xcode change the layout/naming with a `.xcdatamodeld` structure is to do it yourself on disk, then re-add to Xcode

Comment: still relevant after 10 full years!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks to all of you for helping me finally nail this one down.  Here's how I fixed this after renaming my project in Xcode 4.2:

1)  Delete the reference to the *.xcdatamodeld file in your project.  If it's like mine, an editor won't load when you select it.  This tells me a link was broken in the rename.

2)  Right-click on the .xcdoeproj file for your project and select 'Show Package Contents'.

3)  Drag the *.xcdatamodeld file you find there back into your project.  Done.

My app buil

Answer (score 3):

In XCode 4.3.2, it successfully renames the model file but I had to remove it from the project and add it again to make it work. Otherwise it was throwing

Comment: Copying the file in finder and then deleting in xcode aswell as deleting the file not just the reference worked for me and re adding worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Looks like momd missing in resources files. You can check in generated .app.

Make sure it is in compile sources build phase.

And clean/rebuild sometimes helps with xcdatamodels... Especially when creating/renaming them...

Comment: That's the thing. The momd file is not renamed. How can i fix this?

Comment: try a "hard clean" by deleting all build/ content. Check the build log in details to see what's generated (and why). Also take care of versioned models `.xcdatamodel_d_` vs `.xcdatamodel`only models (without d) will end in resources.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a file called `Model.xcdatamodeld` in my project, I decided renaming it to `MyModel.xcdatamodeld` through XCode. It did correctly, however the inner file was still called  `Model.xcdatamodel`. I could not rename it through XCode, so I did through my friend Finder. The problem from now on was that Xcode wasn't opening this file anymore. Then what I did was just searching for it on the `project.pbxproj` and renamed the file name. Now Xcode could open it perfectly.

```
1D707FAE1FA9EBAB00A6D123 /* Model.xcdatamodel */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.xcdatamodel; path = MyModel.xcdatamodel; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

Of course that I also had to rename it on the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 1):

**XCode 10 Update & Swift 4**

Things may have changed a bit since XCode 4.2
It seems simplier in later versions because I just had to :

1. Change `OLD.xcdatamodeld` to `NEW.xcdatamodeld` in fileInspector left tab
2. In `AppDelegate` juste change the reference name : `let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "NEW")`

Comment: No they haven't, I'm using Xcode 11.4 and the problem is still the same. Renaming the `xcdatamodeld` won't rename the `xcdatamodel` file in it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in the following manner: open `.xcdatamodeld` in XCode. In the inspector panel go to the Identity and Type section. In the `Full Path` field click on the arrow icon next to the full path. In Finder duplicate the xcdatamodel that you wish to rename. Rename the duplicate to the desired name. Back in Xcode, click on the directory icon next to the `Location` field. Select the xcdatamodel duplicate that you renamed to the desired name and click `Choose`. You can delete the old original xcdatamodel if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the name of any file in the application bundle ***after*** the app is built. Once the app bundle is fixed, it can't be changed at all.

So, if you want to change the name of the model file on device, especially on user's devices, well, you can't.

However, if you are still in development just change the name of the file in Xcode by clicking on the file's name and changing it.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 4.2, I renamed my model (*.xcdatamodeld) file in project navigator (it automatically renamed *.xcdatamodel file inside a package, and both files in my filesystem).

In `initWithContentsOfURL:` of the `NSManagedObjectModel`, I used a new name.

This resulted in what *@Mustafa* is describing in the question (nil model).

So I tried **adding a new version of my model** and it solved the problem (even though I had no changes in my model).