# Wrong Filename for .mom file in momd folder in iOS Build

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

My team recently renamed the project of an Objective-C iOS app in Xcode and we've determined a larger problem to be the cause of the .mom file within the momd directory to be named wrongly.

Example (not real names):
Our project used to be named "ChinaTown", but was renamed to "Chinatown". Thus inside the Chinatown.momd directory is a ChinaTown.mom file.

How can we ensure that the .mom file within the momd directory is of the correct name and case?

Comment: Project renaming in XCode is a real pain, isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by recreating the data model and deleting the old one. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621178/rename-xcdatamodel-file) stackoverflow thread