# Rename xcdatamodeled file - Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, core-data-migration

How do you rename the xcdatamodeled file in Xcode 7?

The app is currently in production and all I want to do is rename this file. There are no changes to the model itself. The problem is that I keep getting crashes when I rename it.

Picture of error:

[image]

Comment: You might need to amend the code that builds your CoreData stack to use the revised name.  Edit your post to include the code and details of the errors.

Comment: @pbasdf Please see update with picture

Comment: How do you build the CoreData stack?  Are you using Apple's template, which uses the App Delegate to build it?

Comment: Check your managedObjectModel getter method and make sure you have new name there

Comment: @pbasdf Yes it's Apple's template

Comment: @C_X I did rename it there as well `let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("new_name_here", withExtension: "momd")!`

Comment: As per @C_X, look in the App Delegate for the `managedObjectModel` method, and check that it uses the new name.

Comment: @pbasdf Is it this line `let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("new_name_here", withExtension: "momd")!` ? If so I already changed the name here as well and it still crashes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621178/rename-xcdatamodel-file

Comment: That's the line.  Is the xcdatamodeld file included in the Target?

Comment: @pbasdf Not sure how to check that. I never changed anything there.

Comment: I would follow the answers in the question C_X linked to - it's most likely that's the problem.

Comment: @C_X thank you it works